# Designing library to generate dynamic MDX query

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns, mdx

We are generating MDX query dynamically. We pass list of Columns ([DimesnionName].[Attribute.Name] format), Rows ([DimesnionName].[Attribute.Name] format) and Filter ([DimesnionName].[Attribute.Name].[Member Name] format) along with other inputs like, cube name, page number, measure etc.

This information is passed to a C# library and then we use lot of 'If' and 'Else' conditions to process this input and generate MDX query as a string. It requires lot of string manipulation.

You can say it has a workflow. After going through each condition, system generates some output. I am wondering if there is a smarter way to design this library.

1. I want to remove if else conditions.
2. I want to make it more readable.
3. I want to make it more manageable

**My Question is: Is there any design principle I can use? I can think of using Windows WorkFlow. Please provide your suggestions**

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually on here to see if someone has done just that so I don't have to.  No luck so far.  But off the top of my head what you might want to look at is some form of rules engine that will evaluate the state of target string and add your various criteria.

Now I haven't even started to look into the syntax of MDX.  I'm not that far along, but if I wanted to create an engine to create sql queries I'd look at the parts ( simplest case first ) you need list of columns, a table and list of where clauses.  So you could have three or maybe just two basic engine classes one that takes a list of strings and (or better yet a list of expressions) and concatenates them ( or evaluates and then concats them ).  If target string is empty then targetString = "select "+ x else targetString = ", " + x.  Then do something similar with the where expression.  You can get considerably more fancy for that building classes that implement the different forms of where expressions and so on.  Then ultimately you'd pass your engine something like

```
MySqlEngine(new[] {"FirstName", "LastName", "GirlFriendsAddress"},
           new []{EqualsExpression("FirstName","Brown"), EqualsExpression("LastName",Dynamite")},
           "People");
```

and it would return

```
"SELECT FirstName, LastName, GirlFriendsAddress From People Where FirstName = \"Brown\" AND LastName = \"Dynamite\""
```

I would highly recommend using Expressions to evaluate properties on a target model that matches your table.  Then you could make MySqlEnigine(...) you wouldn't have to provide to table name because your model could be named the same and you'd use no strings except for target value of the where clauses.

I know this is not the engine you want but I don't know MDX yet so you'll have to use this as an analogy.

Final thoughts DO NOT USE Window Workflow.  You will want to kill yourself half way through and if you make it all the way through than there will be developers cursing your name for many years in the future.

Good luck

oh and if you build the please open source it and tell me so I don't have to do it.